# Linux C: What does the "S_Ixxxx" permission flag's "S" and "I" actually mean?

Tags: c, linux, function, permissions

On linux, man 2 open, I got explanations of following flags:

```
   S_IRWXU
          00700 user (file owner) has read, write and execute permission

   S_IRUSR
          00400 user has read permission

   S_IWUSR
          00200 user has write permission

   S_IXUSR
          00100 user has execute permission

   S_IRWXG
          00070 group has read, write and execute permission...
```

I wish to know what do the leading letters of "S_I" actually mean, is "S" short for some word, as so does "I"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `S` is probably for [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html).

In the 7th Edition Unix (circa 1979), the documentation for `stat()` included the information:

```
#define S_IFMT 0170000      /* type of file */
#define     S_IFDIR 0040000 /* directory */
#define     S_IFCHR 0020000 /* character special */
#define     S_IFBLK 0060000 /* block special */
#define     S_IFREG 0100000 /* regular */
#define     S_IFIFO 0010000 /* fifo */
#define S_ISUID  04000      /* set user id on execution */
#define S_ISGID  02000      /* set group id on execution */
#define S_ISVTX  01000      /* save swapped text even after use */
#define S_IREAD  00400      /* read permission, owner */
#define S_IWRITE 00200      /* write permission, owner */
#define S_IEXEC  00100      /* execute/search permission, owner */
```

The test macros such as `S_ISREG(mode)` were not present; you had to use an expression such as `(sb->st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG` to test for a regular file.  The macros related to permissions such as `S_IRWXU` or `S_IRUSR` were also undefined.  These were added a decade or so later by POSIX.  It was deemed sufficient (and efficient) to use octal constants.  If you needed symbolic permissions, the value `S_IREAD` was equivalent to `S_IRUSR`, `S_IWRITE` to `S_IWUSR` and `S_IEXEC` to `S_IXUSR`, and simple shifting right by 3 or 6 bits gave the group or other permissions bits.

However, the `S_I` prefix was there uniformly, and POSIX maintained that uniformity as it added symlinks and (Unix domain) sockets, etc. and the extra test macros.

Comment: Unix v6 didn't have the S_ prefix, but all the flags in the inode were prefixed with I and the implementation of stat copied data directly from the inode out to userland without a stat struct being defined. The v7 flags look like mostly the the v6 inode flags with an S_ prefix.

Answer (score 2):

S is probably for stat, I probably is for inode. All these permission flags are saved in inode data structure. For more details about inode, you can read [inode on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)